# Getting Incorrect Image URL in Custom GraphQL Query

Tags: magento2, product-images, graphql

in my Custom Graphql Query, I am trying to get product image Url using `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image`
in this way

```
$this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->getUrl();
```

I am not getting Url correctly
I am getting something like this

> https://baseurl/static/version1627894233/graphql/_view/en_US/Magento_Catalo[…]roduct/placeholder/.jpg

Anyone Help me to get the correct URL
need Help

Comment: Can you please upload full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set store emulation inside your code. Like this below way :

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation
 */
protected $appEmulation;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation
 */
public function __construct(
      ....
      \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation
      ....
) {
      ....
      $this->appEmulation = $appEmulation;
      ....
}

public function getImageUrl()
{
      $this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);
      $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->getUrl();
      $this->appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
}
```

Clean cache and check it.

Comment: Thank you, sir! it worked, you never disappoint us

Comment: Happy to solve !! Happy Coding !!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest :

1 - Check where is really located your images.

2 - Go into the imageHelper and debug it, check if the issue comes from the recording of your image location

After that you may want to create a new Helper overriding the magento one to fix your issue by adapting the process (probably the graph ql root media file isn't properly registered if i had to guess without seing anything).

===========================

That being said; why you don't just get the image using your $product object ? `$product->getThumbnail()`